# Advanced Custom Fields: How do I display the value from a relational page link into another text field

Tags: ajax, advanced-custom-fields, relational

How do I display the value from a relational page link into another text field?

I am creating a Family Tree website for my family. I have set up advanced custom fields where they enter information about their ancestors. To make their experience easier, I am trying to have certain fields populate automatically. For example, if they select their grandmother's name from a relational page link, (each person has their own post created for them), I would then like the value from their relational link selection to appear in real-time in a separate text field, visually. This text field is only there to be used as a label of sorts to indicate where to add the great-grandparent's names. Because as you go deeper into the generations it can get difficult to know where you are at. Having this functionality will orient them quickly as to where to go next.

If this relation link value could populate the Name/Label of the text field that would even be better but I thought that might not be possible.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi there, I found this code but I can't get it to work. I assume that it is meant to be added in my child theme's function.php, but perhaps I am wrong.


add_action('admin_footer', function () {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#acf-field_5c19647c09c56').on('keyup', e => {
    $('#acf-field_5c19648909c57').val(parseFloat(e.target.value));
  })
</script>
<?php
});